# jquery show/hide element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you find the next XX element in jquery? What I'm trying to achieve is that when someone clicks in one of the "event_details_arrow" class, the next "event_detail" class will show/hide.

This is my code, but at the moment is shows/hides all the event_detail classes whenever I click on any of the "event_details_arrow".

```
    $(".event_details_arrow").bind("click", function () {
        $(".event_detail").slideToggle();
    });
                 <tr>
                    <td>yyy</td>
                    <td class="event_details_arrow"><span></span></td>
                    <td class="lastcol"><a href=""><span>Register</span></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="event_detail">
                     <td colspan="3">text</td>
                 </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>yyy</td>
                    <td class="event_details_arrow"><span></span></td>
                    <td class="lastcol"><a href=""><span>Register</span></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="event_detail">
                     <td colspan="3">text</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>yyy</td>
                    <td class="event_details_arrow"><span></span></td>
                    <td class="lastcol"><a href=""><span>Register</span></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="event_detail">
                     <td colspan="3">text</td>
                 </tr>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure about having one parent, you could use something like:

```
$(".event_details_arrow").bind("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: yeah that seems to work. now, I would like to trigger the event on page load and this code only works on the first element. Any idea why?  $(".event_details_arrow").triggerHandler("click");

Comment: sorry, I think you misread my comment? your code works. Now I want to trigger it on page load for every element. How would you do that? this doesn't seem to work: $(".event_details_arrow").triggerHandler("click");

Comment: @user441365 Sorry, you're right. I misread. I'll try something out

Comment: @user441365 Use `.trigger('click')` instead. Works fine.

Comment: ok I'v just fixed it by creating a separate function and calling it on load. Thanks!

Comment: @user441365 "While .trigger() will operate on all elements matched by the jQuery object, .triggerHandler() only affects the first matched element." Comes from [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".event_details_arrow").bind("click", function () {
            $(this).next(".event_detail").slideToggle();
        });
// or
    $(".event_details_arrow").bind("click", function () {
            $(this).closest(".event_detail").slideToggle();
        });
```

perhaps?

Comment: correct that it doesn't work, because the next has to be found from the parent. The next of the arrow is the `.lastCol`

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(".event_details_arrow").bind("click", function () {
            $(this).closest(".event_details_arrow").slideToggle();
        });
```